# Is this an example of UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I would like your help to understand whether the native iOS weather app utilizes or not a **UITabBarController** (or is this a different view controller?) with multiple ViewControllers inside. Here is the screeenshot:

[image]

Doubts:

- Is the bar at the bottom a **tab** with custom images?
- Is each city associated to a ViewController?

Here is a video with the [app behaviour.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhfNzMMm-Vs)

Comment: [Yes/no questions about an example are not a good fit for this site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions). Answers to such questions are rarely useful to anyone except the original asker. The purpose of this site is to create a useful repository of high quality questions with answers. Instead of asking "is this an example of _X_", ask "what is _X_". What makes you this this is **not** an example of an `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, a `UITabBarController` has **tabs** on the bottom. This one is a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled.

Comment: Excellent thanks.. so I guess there is a way to create custom icons for each page.. I will look into this and accept the answer as soon as SO allows me.